# Must it be true that $x_1x_2\dotsm x_n \leq \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_ix_j$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $x_1,~x_2,\dots,x_n$ are positive integers and $n>2$. I want to know that if the relation $x_1x_2\dotsm x_n \leq \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_ix_j$ is true, how I can prove it? Or in which references I can find it?

Comment: When $n=3$, the right hand side is $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1$? or not?

Comment: @mathlove The indices being summed over reads $1\leq i,j\leq 3$ (for n=3). I took that to mean the RHS is the sum of all nine possible combinations of indices: $x_1x_1 + x_2x_2 + x_3x_3 + 2x_1x_2 + 2x_1x_3 + 2x_2x_3$. You seem to be reading the sum as over $1\leq i<j\leq 3$, which I don't think is right.

Comment: @DavidH: Thanks. I thought the same thing. I wrote my comment just to clarify it.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality need not hold. Let the $x_i$ be equal and large, say $N$. Then $x_1x_2\cdots x_n=N^n$, while $\sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n}x_ix_j=\binom{n}{2}N^2$. For $N$ large enough, $N^n$ will be larger than  $\binom{n}{2}N^2$.

Comment: That's right. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. In looking at whether an inequality holds, it can be useful to look at "extreme" cases.